# How to open a file in a subdirectory in c

Tags: c, file-io

I am trying to open a file in a subdirectory called "Files". I know how to open a file in a subdirectory if I know the name:

```
 fopen("./Files/file.txt", "r");
```

However, I am trying to create a file that will open any and all files in the subdirectory without having to know the file names ahead of time. I am using the reaaddir() function to be able to locate the file name, however, I am not sure how to plug it into fopen to open and read the file. The readdir() function automatically saves the file name in dp_>d_name. Then If I do this:

```
fopen("./Files/dp->d_name", "r");
```

the program is going to try to open the file named "dp->d_name" rather than the file name stored at that location.

IF there is not a way to do this, is there a way to change the current working directory from within the program? Every file I want to open is within the same subdirectory, so that would be an acceptable solution.

Here is my code, for reference:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>

void  readFile(int)
{
        DIR *dir;
        struct dirent *dp;
        char * file_name;
        char buffer[100];
        FILE *out;
        FILE *in;
        char outName[] = "filenames.txt";

        if (( out = fopen(outName, "w+")) == NULL )
        {
                printf("Can't open %s for writing.\n", outName);
                return 2;
        }

        dir = opendir("./Files/");
        while ((dp=readdir(dir)) != NULL)
        {
                if ( !strcmp(dp->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(dp->d_name, ".."))
                {
                    //do nothing...
                }
                else
                {
                        if (( in = fopen( dp->d_name, "r")) == NULL)
                        {
                                printf("Can't open %s for writing.\n", dp->d_name);
                                return 2;
                        }

                         fgets(buffer, 100, in);
                         printf("\"%s\"\n", buffer);
                }
        }
        closedir(dir);
        fclose(out);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `strcat()` to concatenate strings.

Comment: You *do* know about e.g. [`snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)?

Comment: You can change directories with `chdir()`.

Comment: Thanks Barmar! I was trying to do that using system("cd ....). I was not aware of the chdir function. It works now.

Comment: OT: This "*`printf("Can't open %s for writing.\n", ...`*" should read "*`printf("Can't open %s for reading.\n", ...`*"

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I had corrected that after I posted it on here.

Answer (score 0):

you can create the full file location in another variable by joining "./Files/" before dp->d_name. you can either use strcat() for it or use create char* with enough size to store the entire location and then fill it using a for loop, and then use this variable in fopen. eg.
if dp->d_name = "f1.txt" then create a variable, 
newFileName =  "./Files/f1.txt" and then fopen(newFileName, "r");